# Expected update behavior on re-saving while using MongoDB's official C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Trying to understand the expected behavior on re-saving a existing document (from a 3+ level object graph) that was previously saved.  Is an update applied to only the top level fields or does it attempt to traverse for nested objects changes?

```
var models = _database.GetCollection<Model>("Models");
var model = models.FindOneAs<Model>(Query.EQ("_id", new ObjectId("4df7bce0dc1c792230912fda")));

// Apply various changes on multi-level object graph...

models.Save(model);
```

When trying the above, nested changes were not being applied to db.

Comment: Can you post full code, with document class and update part? I want try with you.

Answer (score 0):

I've builded test for your problem:

Here is document that i saved into mongodb (with 3 level array deep):

```
{
  "_id": "4dfa48d1872b4a1a50f60033",
  "NestedLevels": [
    {
      "Name": "Nested1",
      "NestedLevels": [
        {
          "Name": "Nested2",
          "NestedLevels": [
            {
              "Name": "Nested3",
              "NestedLevels": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

}

I am loading it from c#, updating Name=Nested3 with another value and saving back, after that i am reading from mongodb updated document and it updated actually.  So i guess problem in some other part of you code.

BTW: If you need i can post here complete test in c#.

**Update:**

Test case:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void MongodbTest()
    {
        var mongoServer = MongoServer.Create("mongodb://localhost:27020");
        var database = mongoServer.GetDatabase("StackoverflowExamples");
        var levels = database.GetCollection("levels");
        var level1 = new Level1();

        var nested1 = new LevelX() { Name = "Nested1" };
        var nested2 = new LevelX() { Name = "Nested2" };
        nested1.NestedLevels.Add(nested2);
        var nested3 = new LevelX() { Name = "Nested3" };
        nested2.NestedLevels.Add(nested3);

        level1.NestedLevels.Add(nested1);

        levels.Insert(level1);

        var item = levels.FindOneAs<Level1>();

        item.NestedLevels[0].NestedLevels[0].NestedLevels[0].Name = 
                                         "Changed nested level 3 name";

        levels.Save(item);

        var itemAfterUpdate = levels.FindOneAs<Level1>();

        Assert.AreEqual("Changed nested level 3 name", 
            itemAfterUpdate.NestedLevels[0].NestedLevels[0].NestedLevels[0].Name);

        levels.RemoveAll();
    }
```

Documents classes:

```
public class Level1
    {
        public Level1()
        {
            Id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId();
            NestedLevels = new List<LevelX>();
        }

        [BsonId]
        public Object Id { get; set; }

        public List<LevelX> NestedLevels { get; set; }
    }

    public class LevelX
    {
        public LevelX()
        {
            NestedLevels = new List<LevelX>();
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public List<LevelX> NestedLevels { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I must be doing something wrong.  Posting your test code would help identifying where i went wrong.  Thx!